# Cascading foreign key cannot be created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a table of Documents:

```
public class Document
{
[Key]
public int DocumentId {get; set;}
public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

I also have a table of DepthDocuments:

```
public class DepthDocument
{
[Key]
public int DepthDocumentId {get; set;}
public int DocumentId {get; set;}
public int Depth {get; set;}
}
```

Every Document has a corresponding DepthDocument.  Both tables have the same number of rows.  I'm trying to tell EF that - when I delete a Document - I also want to delete the corresponding DepthDocument.  I think part of this is creating a 1-1 relationship, which I've tried by adding this to the Document class:

```
    [Required]
    public virtual DepthDocument DepthDocument { get; set; }
```

And then this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.DepthDocument).WithRequiredPrincipal()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But I'm getting:

> Cascading foreign key 'FK_dbo.DepthDocument_dbo.Document_DepthDocumentId' cannot
>   be created where the referencing column 'DepthDocument.DepthDocumentId' is an
>   identity column.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

I have DocumentId and DepthDocumentId columns because I'm creating the DepthDocument table now, and I need to create one new DepthDocument per Document in a seed method:

```
foreach (var document in context.Documents.ToList())
        {

            context.DepthDocuments.AddOrUpdate(
            d => d.DocumentId,
            new DepthDocument()
            {
                DocumentId = document.DocumentId, // can I do this?  I tried and ran into problems with missing entries not getting added
                // other props
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `DepthDocument` to look like this:

```
public class DepthDocument
{
[Key]
public int DocumentId {get; set;}
public int Depth {get; set;}
}
```

Since it's a 1:1 relationship and `DepthDocument` can't exist without a matching `Document` then there isn't any reason for `DepthDocument` to use a different key.

Comment: I gave it its own Id because I'm just now adding the DepthDocument table, so in order to seed the data and specify each entry's Id (to match every one of the existing Documents), I added the column.  Is it possible to specify the DocumentId in the seed data on the new table?  I'll update my card to show you what I mean